# change selection type for left click-drag

Tags: edit-mode

So in blender 2.8 you can just click and drag to select multiple objects (a bit like box-select). I really like this because it just feels natural. However, at first this was as I described: click and drag would be like box-select, but after a while it changed to lasso-select in the Edit mode (in object mode it is still box-select) and now it even became something really different: if I now click and drag in edit mode, it will grab a vertex and drag it as if I pressed `g`.

I'm guessing that I somehow pressed a key-combination to change this setting. But I don't know what key I would have pressed and I really can't live with this. Does anyone know how to change this so I can go back to the box-select or lasso-select by clicking and dragging the cursor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Blender's selection tool supports four different modes, which are accessed from the top icon in the Tools menu, on the left side of the screen. The click-and-drag option is the current default setting, and is just called "Select"; the tool can also be set to box selection, lasso selection and circle selection modes. The keyboard shortcut to cycle through the options is <kbd>W</kbd>, which is presumably what the OP pressed accidentally.

To reset your preferred selection mode, click and hold the Select tool icon until a little menu pops up with the four options.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following shortcuts to switch *Selection Types*:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> > <kbd>B</kbd> for *Select Box*

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> > <kbd>C</kbd> for *Select Circle*

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> > <kbd>L</kbd> for *Select Lasso*

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> > <kbd>W</kbd> for *Tweak*

Or you can just press <kbd>W</kbd> to cycle between the different types.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the upper left corner and press <kbd>W</kbd>, this changes selection mode in *Edit* and *Object mode*

I've been looking for a way to fix this and started spamming <kbd>W</kbd> in frustration and saw it changing.