Move the vertex/point without have to select it first
I'm in edit mode and I want to move some points. I want to be able to click and drag them one by one directly. How can I do this ? right now , I have to select (box select) the point then press 'G' to move and then have to repeat this steps for every point I want to move. Is it possible to move the vertex directly by clicking dan dragging it.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126245/change-selection-type-for-left-click-drag?rq=1

In edit mod press and hold the 'select' (top most tool on the left panel) , switch from default 'select box' to 'tweak' :

When tweak is active, we can move object directly by clicking and dragging.

If you are moving them one at a time you don't need to use box select, you can just click on them with left or right mouse button (which ever you set for selection when you installed blender) to select them.
If, when selecting them, you keep the mouse button pressed and drag it, it will move them around as when pressing G

You need to set the cursor to 'Tweak' mode first to do that. You can cycle between the selection options with the 'W' key. The top left toolbar select icon changes each time you hit W and you can hover over it to see (and change) which mode you're in.

To clarify, Box select mode is the default when installing Blender if you've not changed it in the Settings.
